# Using pandas apply function on multilevel DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose this is my multilevel DataFrame:

```
States = pd.DataFrame({'Alaska' : [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Arizona': [5, 6, 7, 8]}, 
                      index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B'], ['x','y']],
                      labels=[[1,1,0,0],[1,0,1,0]])).T
```

I'm trying to derive new variables from this DataFrame.

```
def scoring_algorithm(x):
    return x[('A', 'x')] + 100
States.apply(scoring_algorithm)
```

But this throws an error

`KeyError: (('A', 'x'), 'occurred at index (B, y)')`

I assume from the error that my column selector `('A', 'x')` is not satisfactory, but I can't find any resources for how to use this for an apply function.

Note: I need the apply function or something similar because the final scoring algorithm requires several columns as inputs to the apply function.

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: Thanks for the good, reproducible example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently applying to the index.

```
df.apply(fxn)
```

is equivalent to:

```
df.apply(fxn, axis='index')
```

You need to apply to the columns.

```
df.apply(fxn, axis='columns')
```

So for you:

```
States.apply(scoring_algorithm, axis='columns')
```

and I get:

```
Alaska     104
Arizona    108
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Terrific! This is perfect. Thank you!